# Minor edit limitation

Tags: discussion, editing

When you wanna edit some post you can have this kind of warning message:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to
>   improve in this post?

You can't submit your edit (at least when you haven't the edit privilege as in my case). Sometimes I want to edit a new post that I see because of missing command highlight or equivalent. And when you have only a few modification as only two "`" to put, you just can't.

Why this limitation? Is it possible to go throught it?

Comment: Have you seen [Edit length limits](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4631) ?

Comment: @PaulGessler No. I've make some research on the subject and didn't find anything. My bad. This subject coulb be closed I think